# How to find binary representation of large numbers?

Tags: c

I wanted to convert a number to binary so i used the classic algorithm to solve the problem but at some point i don't get the true value because i exceed the max value of `int`
is there any other solution to find the binary representation of lager numbers, beside using `long`
or `long long`?

Comment: What "classic algorithm" are you referring to? Please show your code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it is clear what you have done and also so that we can point out any errors or suggestions based on your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are outside the range that your machine can natively represent then you will have to switch to arbitrary-precision math. Find the largest power of two smaller than your target number, subtract, find the next largest subtract again and so on until you have nothing left.